# What is the logic by which tokens are ordered when creating a new Uniswap V2 pair?

Tags: solidity, addresses, uniswap, solidity-0.5.x

When creating a new pair contract via the [UniswapV2Factory](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/v1.0.1/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol) contract, the order in which tokens get assigned in storage (that is, the `token0` and `token1` vars) [cannot](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/v1.0.1/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L25) be arbitrarily set by the caller:

```
(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
```

What does `tokenA < tokenB` do in Solidity? The vars are `address` types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy to see what that comparison does with a hands-on approach on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/):

```
pragma solidity =0.5.16;

contract AddressComparison {
    function cmp(address token0, address token1) external pure returns (bool) {
        return token0 < token1;
    }
}
```

Say you're passing the following two addresses as inputs:

- token0 = 0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599
- token1 = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48

The function returns `true`:

[image: Remix Screenshot #1]

It looks like Solidity compares the numerical value of the addresses (that is, their hexadecimal values). Since `token1`'s first digit is greater in value than `token0`'s digit (`0xA` versus `0x2`), the comparison yields `true`.

Let's see another example to drive the point home:

- token0 = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2
- token1 = 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48

This time, the function returns `false`:

[image: Remix Screenshot #2]

You can probably guess why: `0xC` is bigger than `0xA`.

Most likely Uniswap did this to reduce the costs of integration. If everybody knows that tokens are always ordered by their hexadecimal value in a Uniswap v2 pair, clients don't have to query the blockchain to find out the order of the tokens in the pool provided they know the token addresses.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, but i kinda want to add in on this. Could you please help check with this issue, they are kinda related..  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/137654/set-tokena-as-token0-for-uniswapv2-liquidity-pair-contract