# Set tokenA as token0 for UniswapV2 liquidity pair contract

Tags: solidity, uniswap, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider, pairings

Hello guys I need some help!

Could someone explain me how to set the token order (token0 / token1) of a liquidity pair?

I’m using UniswapsV2 - Factory contract.

Currently when i create a pool with tokenA & tokenB. I expect tokenA to become token0, and tokenB to become token1. But this is not the case..

The function I use to create pair:

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
```

I did some digging in the code of the contract, and the problem i see is: the contract sorts the token order by itself. Take a look at this code: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/4dd59067c76dea4a0e8e4bfdda41877a6b16dedc/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L25

```
(address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
```

So basically it sorts the token by a lower / higher value address ..

**But what if tokenB has a higher value then tokenA but i still want tokenA to be token0 and tokenB to become token1.**

How can i achieve this?

My liquidity pair should be:

**TEST/WETH**  ✅

But now it becomes:

**WETH/TEST** ❌

I really hope someone could help me with this!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't choose your own order. The order is determinated based on the tokens addresses.